# Twitter Bootstrap carousel arrows not centered vertically depending on glyphicon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a Twitter Bootstrap carousel with the default arrows (glyphicon-chevron-left and glyphicon-chevron-right). These are nicely centered vertically in the carousel.

I though about replacing these icons with two different icons, namely glyphicon-circle-arrow-left and glyphicon-circle-arrow-right. But for some reason, when only replacing the icons, they are suddenly not centered vertically anymore. I can't find out why.

This is the nicely centered version (http://jsfiddle.net/AdF6b):

```
    <div class="row">
      <div  id="foto-carousel" class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#foto-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#foto-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#foto-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="active item">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/1600/800/city/1">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h4>Slide 1</h4>
              <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/1600/800/city/3">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h4>Slide 2</h4>
              <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/1600/800/city/5">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h4>Slide 3</h4>
              <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#foto-carousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> -->
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#foto-carousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

The non centered version (http://jsfiddle.net/AdF6b/1/):

```
<div class="row">
      <div  id="foto-carousel" class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#foto-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#foto-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#foto-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="active item">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/1600/800/city/1">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h4>Slide 1</h4>
              <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/1600/800/city/3">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h4>Slide 2</h4>
              <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/1600/800/city/5">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h4>Slide 3</h4>
              <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#foto-carousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#foto-carousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

Why are the arrows in the second version not centered? The only difference is the glyphicon classes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have to admit, this issue is a bit strange. In Twitter Bootstrap, there are this particular lines:

```
.carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .icon-next, 
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control 
.glyphicon-chevron-right, .glyphicon-circle-arrow-left {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Like you see, there is no `.glyphicon-circle-arrow-left` and no `.glyphicon-circle-arrow-right` class specified. So you can simply add it and everything should work fine:

```
.carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .icon-next, 
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control 
.glyphicon-chevron-right, .glyphicon-circle-arrow-left, 
.carousel-control .glyphicon-circle-arrow-left, 
.carousel-control .glyphicon-circle-arrow-right {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: Or just `.carousel-control span { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.4 and you can use what ever glyphicon you like if you add the class **icon-prev** (left arrow) and **icon-next** to your (glyphicon).

I changed my glyphicon from the default .glyphicon-chevron-left to use .glyphicon-menu-left and right.

```html
<a class='left carousel-control' href='#carousel-custom' data-slide='prev'>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left icon-prev'></span>
</a>
<a class='right carousel-control' href='#carousel-custom' data-slide='next'>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right icon-next'></span>
</a>
```

Comment: This does not work. In fact using icon-prev and icon-next will override the glyphicon of your choice.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Flixer, but perhaps it would be better not to edit the original Bootstrap css files. Instead, you can put that lines:

```
/* Bootstrap: Center carousel arrow icons   */
.carousel-control .glyphicon-arrow-left, 
.carousel-control .glyphicon-arrow-right {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

in your own project css file. This may avoid problems when upgrading to new Bootstrap versions.