# Vertically center glyphicons in carousel-control with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I've created an image slider in Bootstrap. I set up a `carousel-control` class to cycle through the images. I also tried adding right and left glyphicons to the control panels. When I add the `glyphicon-chevron` it results as centered both vertically and horizontally, but if I change it to `glyphicon-triangle` the glyphicons don't align in the center of the `carousel-control` panels.

carousel html with `glyphicon-chevron`:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" style="width: 800px; heigh:400px; margin: 0 auto">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class='item active'>
            <img src='http://blog.burnsfilmcenter.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Samsara2.png' alt='info1' />
            <div class='carousel-caption'>
                <h1>info1</h1>
                <p>text here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='item'>
            <img src='http://blog.burnsfilmcenter.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Samsara2.png' alt='info2' />
            <div class='carousel-caption'>
                <h1>info2</h1>
                <p>text here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-carousel-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Result:

[image: chevron]

carousel html with `glyphicon-triangle`:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" style="width: 800px; heigh:400px; margin: 0 auto">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class='item active'>
            <img src='http://blog.burnsfilmcenter.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Samsara2.png' alt='info1' />
            <div class='carousel-caption'>
                <h1>info1</h1>
                <p>text here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='item'>
            <img src='http://blog.burnsfilmcenter.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Samsara2.png' alt='info2' />
            <div class='carousel-caption'>
                <h1>info2</h1>
                <p>text here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Result:

[image: triangle]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap carousel arrows not centered vertically depending on glyphicon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588819/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-arrows-not-centered-vertically-depending-on-glyphicon)

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap css is specifically targeting the .glyphicon-chevron-right class (see code below).

You'd need to add the same css in your own stylesheet to target your new glyphicon triangle.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right, .carousel-control .icon-next, .carousel-control .icon-prev {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right, .carousel-control .icon-next {
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -10px;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. The `glyphicon-chevron` is automatically where it should be, but the `glyphicon-triangle` shifts to the top. Where did you get icon-prev and icon-next from. Could you leave a working demo?

Comment: See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/e22a73fd381edef4620a758099e5c16ae1168e85/less/carousel.less#L126

Comment: The code I've pasted above is from the bootstrap.css file and it is what is styling the glyphicon-chevron-left. If you want to replace .glyphicon-chevron-left (and right) with the triangle glyphicon then you'll have to update your css to use the above css to target .glyphicon-triangle-left / .glyphicon-triangle-right as well.

Comment: I copied and pasted what you have, changed chevron to triangle, and it doesn't work :).